# Is there a convention when notating sets or summations?

Tags: notation, convention

I have a background in physics and usually when you denote a set, summation or for-loop one says "for every i in N". The index is usually i and the total number of the set or population is N. Then you include a second set. You take j as the index and M as the total number in your set. In my experience these i and N, as well as j and M "belong together".

Now I'm also reading about optimisation problems in operations research and it seems as if they "connect" the letters i and M as well as j and N. Is there any convention for this?

Comment: I think it would help to have specific examples. Everything you’ve stated in your post is a bit vague, making it hard to help you (not only that, but it is often the case that the notation has a specific meaning in a given context, but that meaning might be different in a separate context).

Comment: It sounds like you are asking what letters are commonly used in what contexts for what purposes... Yes, it is common to have the letter $i$ represent an index (*i for index*), and if more indices are needed to continue using $i,j,k,\ell$.  Next, it is common to have $n$ be the number of items or number of iterations (*n for number*), and if you need more then $m$ can be used as well.  In most cases, $i$ and $n$ are the more common letters.  In the event that you have two loops, whether you choose to have $i$ and $n$ together as they are the common and $j,m$ together as the less...

Comment: ...or have $i$ and $m$ together as they appear first alphabetically while having $j$ and $n$ together... that is entirely personal preference.  The end result is that *it doesn't matter*!  [A rose by any other name would smell as sweet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_rose_by_any_other_name_would_smell_as_sweet).  So long as things are clearly labeled, do whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in optimization $i$ is often used to index constraints, and $j$ for variables because the constraint matrix for a linear programming problem has one row for each constraint and once column for each variable.  In linear algebra, a generic matrix has dimensions $m \times n$, with entries indexed by $(i,j)$.  In mathematics, set names are often capital letters.  So $M$ and $N$ are natural choices for the sets of rows/constraints and columns/variables, respectively.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Now I understand the convention between those indices and dimensions. Like you said it is probably due to the usual notation in linear algebra. Thank you.